# Using HTML, CSS & JS to create a fixed header that shrinks on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, header

I am attempting to replicate the work from this site:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMwWyj

But it is failing and I cannot get the javascript to work as intended. I am using embedded javascript and will post all code underneath. The expected outcome is on the hyperlinked page, you can see how the header is supposed to shrink in size once the user has scrolled down the page.

```css
@import compass;


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bruss';
    src: url('bruss-webfont.eot');
    src: url('bruss-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('bruss-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('bruss-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('bruss-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('bruss-webfont.svg#Bruss') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
 background-color: #1d3558; 

}

h1 {
   font-family: Bruss;
   font-size: 4em;
   color: #d3d3d3;
   text-align: center;

}

body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
  /* animation magic */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 180px auto;
}

.shrink {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- 
 Sunday, 31st January 2016. | v . 01
-->

<html>
 <head>

 <title>Test example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css"/>
 <script>
  $(document).on("scroll", function(){
  if
      ($(document).scrollTop() > 100){
    $("header").addClass("shrink");
   updateSliderMargin();
  }
  else
  {
   $("header").removeClass("shrink");
   updateSliderMargin();
  }
 });
 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <header>
 <h1>
  Test example
      </h1>
 </header>




 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time, as you can probably tell from poor indentation and other bad practice I am new to this, so any general comments on how to make code more robust is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the header has the CSS transition property

```
/* animation magic */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out
```

And two classes **.shrink** and **.header**, in **.header** the padding top and bottom is set to 60px and in **.shrink** the padding top and bottom is set to 20px.
Using jQuery to detect the window's scroll level

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("header").addClass("shrink");
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("shrink");
  }
});
```

the classes are swapped, and because of the CSS transition property in the header the change in the padding is animated.

Now on to the fun stuff, i've created a working example for you without all the extra content.
(do forgive me for the "fake content" needed some "content" to scroll)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    * {margin:0;padding:0;}
    .header {width:100%;height:20px;position:fixed;top:0;padding:40px 0;background-color:#ff0;transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;line-height:20px;}
    .shrink {padding:10px 0}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $(".header").addClass("shrink");
        } else {
          $(".header").removeClass("shrink");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    It's Me!
  </header>
  <div class="fake-content">
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
    lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />lorem lorem<br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
           //animate(css property,time,callback)
           $('header').animate({'padding':'20px 0'},1000,function(){      
             //callback animation
             //If you need you can add more animations here, like a chained animation
             console.log('End');
           }); 
       }else{
          $('header').animate({'padding':'0'},1000); 
      }
   });
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery to add a class to nav on scroll like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scroll > 80) {
    $('nav').addClass('nav-shrink');
} else {    
   $('nav').removeClass('nav-shrink');
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxqt8qqu/

I set the height of the nav with my li element's padding. I add a class of "nav-shrink" to the nav when user has scrolled 80px from the top, and decrease the padding on the nav's li element using the new class. Be sure to use css ease transition on the li element to get the easing effect on the height change.